# How to merge aggregation bucket in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl

**Query**

```
GET /_search
{
  "size" : 0,
  "query" : {
    "ids" : {
      "types" : [ ],
      "values" : [ "someId1", "someId2", "someId3" ... ]
    }
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "how_to_merge" : {
      "terms" : {
        "field" : "country",
        "size" : 50
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Result**

```
{
   ...
   "aggregations": {
      "how_to_merge": {
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
         "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "KR",
               "doc_count": 90
            },
            {
               "key": "JP",
               "doc_count": 83
            },
            {
               "key": "US",
               "doc_count": 50
            },
            {
               "key": "BE",
               "doc_count": 9
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

I want to merge "KR" and "JP" and "US"

And change key name to "NEW_RESULT"

So result must like this:

```
{
   ...
   "aggregations": {
      "how_to_merge": {
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
         "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "NEW_RESULT",
               "doc_count": 223
            },
            {
               "key": "BE",
               "doc_count": 9
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Is it possible in elasticsearch query?

I cannot use a client-side solution since there are too many entities and retrieving all of them and merging would be probably too slow for my application.

Thanks for your help and comments!

Answer (score 0):

You can try writing a [script](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-script) for that though I would recommend benchmarking this approach against the client-side processing since it might be quite slow.